# Swift - value of bool being changed without doing anything? Cant find where its being altered?

Tags: ios, swift

I swear to god I have a rogue variable here - I have a bool `menuUp` that simply tells whether some menu buttons have been moved up or not.

I first declare the bool as false then depending on the bool (if the menu is up or not), an animation will run on a swipe gesture/function.

```
var menuUp = Bool(false) //at class level
```

I have set numerous breakpoints and print statements but it seems as though the bool is being modified without me doing anything. When the app loads I have my super view controller call this function, printing the following and making `menuup` true.

```
func moveMenuUp(sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        print("menu up:")
        print(menuUp)

        if !menuUp && !externalViewUp
        {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping:
                0.65, initialSpringVelocity: 1.2, options: [], animations: {

                    //above change the duration to the time it will take,
                    //and fiddle with the springs between 0-1 until you are happy with the effect.
                    self.menuBtn1.center.y -= screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    self.menuBtn2.center.y -= screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    self.menuBtn3.center.y -= screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    //chnage frame however you want to here

                }, completion: { finished in
                    //code that runs after the transition is complete here

            })
            menuUp = !menuUp
        }

        print(menuUp)

    }
```

[image]

So its true. Great. THEN in another class I reference this super viecontorller like this and on a button try to call the menu down function, which can also be called by swiping down on the super view controller -

```
let superv : StarterViewController = StarterViewController (nibName: "StarterViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Then

```
func showIdeaView()
    {
        networkTimer.invalidate()

         superv.moveMenuDown(self) //THIS NEEDS WORK!! BOOL ISSUES!

        externalViewUp = true

        viewGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
        self.addChildViewController(v)
        self.view.addSubview(v.view)
        v.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        v.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(v.view)

    }
```

which calls

```
func moveMenuDown(sender: AnyObject!)
    {
        print("moving down!!!")
        print(menuUp)

        if menuUp == true {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping:
                0.65, initialSpringVelocity: 1.2, options: [], animations: {

                    //above change the duration to the time it will take,
                    //and fiddle with the springs between 0-1 until you are happy with the effect.
                    self.menuBtn1.center.y += screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    self.menuBtn2.center.y += screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    self.menuBtn3.center.y += screenSize.height * (122/568)
                    //chnage frame however you want to here

                }, completion: { finished in
                    //code that runs after the transition is complete here

            })
        menuUp = !menuUp
            }

        print(menuUp)

    }
```

And this function IS CALLEd however it prints - 
[image]
And at the beginning of the function that calls the above func Ive printed out the bool and it is false here also.

Oddly, when I trigger `moveMenuDown`  with a swipe it outputs correctly (starts true, ends false).

The menu is still clearly up I can see it so I KNOW the bool should not/is not false.

Because it is reading ht bool as false, it does not call the animation and move th menu down in `moveMenuDown`. This is a major problem.

What can I do here? Ive tried clicking the magnify glass to find all the places I reference the bool but I don't change it ANYWHERE outside the super view controller and I only changed it TWICE in those 2 functions.

Whats going on?

EDIT:

I now have `weak var superv: StarterViewController!` in the class of the super view controller and Ive written in the other, sub view controller:

```
 let s  = StarterViewController()
```

and in viewdidLoad:

```
s.superv = self
```

but getting the error [image]

Comment: When you initialize a `StarterViewController`, are you sure you're not initializing a second instance of `menuUp`?

Comment: You can add a breakpoint to break when its value changes

Comment: @SausageDioxide how do I do that? Im not versed in breakpoints

Comment: Implement the `didSet` property observer on `menuUp`, and set a break point in it. See if you can find the unexpected change.

Comment: That could be possible.. if I call moveMenuDown on parentviewcontroller instead of superv the way I set it up will I still be doing that or.. what would be the correct approach

Comment: @Fujia Ive been googling.. how do I do that? I think AaronBrager might be right but I have no way to prove that at the moment

Comment: shouldnt `menuUp = !menuUp` be in the completion handler of the animation? (and also the print)

Comment: @skyguy google 'swift property observer'

Comment: Did the animation in `menuDown` occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
let superv : StarterViewController = 
    StarterViewController (nibName: "StarterViewController", bundle: nil)
```

You are actually creating a *new* instance of `StarterViewController`! Whenever a `StarterViewController` is created, its instance properties get initialized. One of them is `menuUp`, which gets initialized to `false`.

Do you see that? The `superv` you created is not the controller which has `menuUp` set to true earlier. It's a completely different and independent instance of `StarterViewController`.

To fix this, you need to assign `self` to `superv` after you created the "another class" that you were talking about.

```
let theOtherClass = TheOtherClass(...)
theOtherClass.superv = self
```

And also, you should change the declaration of `superv` to this:

```
weak var superv: StarterViewController!
```

Comment: Thank you. starting to understand. Where and in what classes are you declaring these?

Comment: Please look at my question for what I did -  need some help

Comment: It's easy. Just change your current declaration of `superv` to the above. And how do you create the other class you mentioned? Just after you create that other class and put it in a variable called `theOtherClass` pr something, write `theOtherClass.superv = self` @skyguy

Answer (score -2):

add a property observer like below

```
var menuUp = Bool(false)  { //at class level
    didSet {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Add a debug point in *print("")* line and see who is changing it.